# Proving that a particular map is an embedding from the Klein bottle into $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, quotient-spaces, klein-bottle

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with the above:

> Show that the map $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4} $ given by $$g(x, y)=((a+r\cos2\pi y)\cos 2 \pi x, (a+r\cos 2 \pi y)\sin 2 \pi x, r\sin 2 \pi y \cdot \cos \pi x, r\sin 2 \pi y \cdot \sin \pi x)  $$ induces an embedding $C^{\infty}$ from the Klein's Bottle into $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

**Important:** it does not specify anything about the numbers $a$ and $r$, but I think they have to obey something like $0<r<a$.

**Remark:** we have 3 ways to construct the Klein's bottle, as follow:

> $\bullet$ $\mathbb{R}^{2}/G$ :  where $G=\langle f_1, f_2\rangle$, such that, $f_1, f_2:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by $f_1(x, y)=(x, y+1)$ and $f_2(x, y)=(x+1, 1-y)$.
>
> $\bullet$ $(S^{1}\times \mathbb{R})/H$ : where $H$ is the ciclic group spanned by $h:S^{1}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^{1}\times \mathbb{R}$ given by $h((x, y), z)=h(x, y, z)=(x, -y, z+1)$.
>
> $\bullet$ $(S^{1}\times S^{1})/K $ : where $K=\{ I_{S^{1}\times S^{1}}, k\}$, such that $I_{S^{1}\times S^{1}}$ is the identity and $k:S^{1}\times S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}\times S^{1}$ is given by $k(x, y)=(\overline{x}, -y)$.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Choose the first construction, showing that $g$ collapses the $G$-orbits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in three steps.

> - First prove that $g\circ f_1=g\circ f_2=g$. 
>     Therefore you have that for any $h\in G$, 
>     $g\circ h=g.$

This implies that $g:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^4$ factors to a continuous map $$\tilde{g}:\Bbb R^2/G\to \Bbb R^4.$$

> - Then prove that $\tilde{g}:\Bbb R^2/G\to \Bbb R^4$ is one-to-one.

This statement is equivalent to the fact that for any $(x,y)$ and $(x^\prime,y^\prime)$ in $\Bbb R^2$, $g(x,y)=g(x^\prime,y^\prime)$ if and only if there is an element $h\in G$ such that $h(x,y)=(x^\prime,y^\prime)$. Note that we already did the implication $(\Leftarrow)$.

From the fact that the Klein bottle is compact and $\Bbb R^4$ is Hausdorff, $\tilde{g}$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.

> - Finally prove that $g:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^4$ is a $C^\infty$ immersion.

From general theorems about group action on manifold etc, you have that $g$ is a $C^\infty$ immersion if and only if $\tilde{g}$ is a $C^\infty$ immersion (you can prove it again, by using $\tilde{g}\circ p=g$ where $p:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2/G$, and the fact that $p$ is a local diffeomorphism).

Therefore the induced map $\tilde{g}$ is an embedding, which is what you wanted.

**Some details for the last step:**

For $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ we have 
$$d_{(x,y)}g= \begin{pmatrix} 
-2\pi(a+r\cos(2\pi y))\sin(2\pi x) & -2\pi r\sin(2\pi y)\cos(2\pi x)\\ 
2\pi(a+r\cos(2\pi y))\cos(2\pi x) & -2\pi r\sin(2\pi y)\sin(2\pi x)\\
-r\pi\sin(2\pi y)\sin(\pi x) & 2\pi r\cos(2\pi y)\cos(\pi x)\\
r\pi\sin(2\pi y)\cos(\pi x) & 2\pi r\cos(2\pi y)\sin(\pi x)\\  
\end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant of the submatrix with the first two rows is
$$(-2\pi(a+r\cos(2\pi y))\sin(2\pi x))\times(-2\pi r\sin(2\pi y)\sin(2\pi x))\\-  (-2\pi r\sin(2\pi y)\cos(2\pi x))\times(2\pi(a+r\cos(2\pi y))\cos(2\pi x))\\=r(2\pi)^2(a+r\cos(2\pi y))\sin(2\pi y)$$
which is non-zero if and only if $\sin(2\pi y)\neq 0$. In the case where $\sin(2\pi y)= 0$ we have 
$$d_{(x,y)}g= \begin{pmatrix} 
-2\pi(a+r\cos(2\pi y))\sin(2\pi x) & 0\\ 
2\pi(a+r\cos(2\pi y))\cos(2\pi x) & 0\\
0 & 2\pi r\cos(2\pi y)\cos(\pi x)\\
0 & 2\pi r\cos(2\pi y)\sin(\pi x)\\  
\end{pmatrix}$$
which has clearly rank $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatelly I'm still stucked in the details. Such as in step two.

Comment: @ArkPDEnational I added some details for the second step. Do you need more details on this step or on some other step?

Comment: Thanks for the additions. I'll continue my proof, if I got stuck again in something, I'll ask you for help.

Comment: one question about step one: it seems that $g\circ f_{2}=g$ doesn't work, because $\sin(-2\pi y)=-\sin2\pi y$.

Comment: @ArkPDEnational yes you are correct something doesn't work. I should have checked this more carefully. Are you sure the second coordinate is $(a+r\cos(2\pi x))\sin(2\pi y)$ and not $(a+r\cos(2\pi x))\sin(2\pi x)$?

Comment: Yes. And we have $\sin 2\pi y$ in another two coordinates. I have a suggestion: doesn't your second step that $g$ is constant on the fibers of $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}/G$ (the quotient map)? Because, in this case, we could apply Theorem 4.30 of Lee - Smooth Manifolds to obtain $\tilde{g}$. What do you think?

Comment: Yes but the $\sin(2\pi y)$ in the last 2 coordinates doesn't bother us because of the $\cos \pi x$ and the $\sin \pi x$. The only problem is that $g\circ f_2=g$ doesn't hold for the second coordinate. For your suggestion, the thing is that being constant on the fibers is equivalent to satisfying $g\circ h=g$ for $h\in G$ which is equivalent to $g\circ f_1=g\circ f_2=g$. May I ask where you got the problem from?

Comment: Oh I see. That's right, we need the first one. But as we will have $\sin(2\pi (1-y))\cos (2\pi x)$ it still won't work, right? I got it from some class notes on properly discontinuous groups. But I've been struggling to solve for some time, haha.

Comment: @ArkPDEnational No it works because $\sin(2\pi(1-y))\cos(\pi (x+1))=(-\sin(2\pi y))(-\cos(\pi x))=\sin(2\pi y)\cos(\pi x)$. If in the second equation you change $\sin(2\pi y)$ by $\sin(2\pi x)$, the expression of $g$ becomes much more symmetric and the first step works. Maybe you can try to do the other steps with this correction and if in the end everything works it's probably what was meant to be written. Written like this, $g$ doesn't factor to a map $\Bbb R^2/G\to \Bbb R^4$ so you have to change something...

Comment: I'm going to change it for $x$ and look forward in solving the steps.

Comment: Everything went out very well, but I can't find the minor 2x2 that has non zero determinant, such that $dg$ is injective.

Comment: @ArkPDEnational I added some details for this last step.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already marked your answer as the right one.

Comment: I saw that you are good with geometry problems. I'm sending you one question that I found (while looking for some results) and none give a hint to solve. Maybe you could help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260364/prove-that-the-group-is-properly-discontinuous